# Cannot auto scale childs in a LinearLayout using weight 1 and width 0 in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have 12 textviews in a linear layout which is included in a relative layout, and I use for each child width=0 and weight=1 but nothing happens. Shouldnt be stretch to fit width? This is my layout. I use this for a drag and drop situation.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/ChoicesLayout"
        android:weightSum="12">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtChoice1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@color/DarkPrimary"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:elevation="5dp"/>

            ........

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: weight is applied in the same direction as the orientation.

Comment: can you explain this please?

Comment: Sorry, I might have misread the question. Try not putting your linearLayout in a relative layout and see if it works. It looks strange that you have android:layout_weight="1" and you say that it is inside a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I changed relative layout to linear layout but still the same

Comment: post full layout code..

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is the following:

Because I was controlling the Textview if it was visible or not, I should have placed View.GONE and not View.Invisible in

```
TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

With invisible there was no space to auto scale

Comment: actually invisible view don't loose occupied space.